# How does document.write() influence the functionality of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a client which uses *jQuery* and *jqxWidget*  jqxMenu sometimes (approx. 3 of 10 times) fails on only one particular page to be 'enriched' with the appropriate CSS styles (in order to make it a jqxMenu).

The included code fragments for the jqxMenu works on each other page of the client.
The only difference to the working pages is that the failing page also includes Javascript from another server to dynamically display options.

The remotely included code looks like:

```
document.write('<table cellspacing="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" align="center">');
document.write('<tr>');
document.write('<td><a href="http://www.someurl.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://someimage.com/jsp/icons/someimage.gif" border="0" 
...
document.write('</tr>');
document.write('</table>');
```

When I embed the generated table statically in my code the issue doesn't occur.

Static variant which fixes the issue:

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellspacing="2" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.someurl.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://someimage.com/jsp/icons/someimage.gif" border="0" 
...
</tr>
</table>
```

The question is: Is there a problem using `document.write()` in conjunction with *jQuery* and/or jqWidgets?

What could be a workaround (thinking of wrapper, since parsing the  and use jQuery to put them seems to be overkill)?

Comment: try to call your jquery code after document.write your problem will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write` blocks the execution of jQuery code since jQuery acts on elements already in the DOM, while as using document.write, these elements don't exist. so jQuery is actually unable to find your DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the div supposed to become a jqMenu is already in the DOM tree (static). The dynamically reloaded images are just additional, seems that the jQuery invocations are skipped instead of delayed.

Comment: Although since doesn't exactly explains the faced effects, removing the document.write() helped.